# How to save address type of user as comment in the order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I have a `select` in the checkout which contains the user's address type (residential or business) and I would need to save the same as a comment in the request, however I do not know how to proceed to get the result.

**`Select` Code:**

```
<select class="required-entry" id="comments" name="comments" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="validate-select onestep required-entry">
   <option>Select</option>
       <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
       <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

I've already saved a field as comment in the request, which would be the reference points from the code below:

**Reference field input code:**

```
<label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Referência: ') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
   <input class="input-text required-entry" id="comments" name="comments" title="<?php echo $this->__('Reference point') ?>" />
</div>
```

**Code in Observer.php of the magento checkout module:**

```
 if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Consultor do atendimento: ' . $oscOrderData['comments']);
        $order->save();
    }
```

**Note: I try to use the same logic, putting the `name` and `id` of the `select` as comments, but when the request is finalized, one overwrites the other and duplicating this code in Observer.php and assigning a new `name` and `id`, the same thing happens, one overrides the other.**

Would it not be possible, for example, to concatenate the two so that they may be saved together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is change the code contained in the Observer.php file to save the data from an `Array`. For this to happen, the fields in the `HTML` code must be changed as well.

**Updated `HTML` field code:**

```
 <label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Reference: ') ?></label>
      <div class="input-box">
          <input style="width: 100% !important;" class="input-text" id="comments_1" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('
Reference points:') ?>" />
       </div>
    </div>

       <div class="field info">
        <label for="commentsEnd" class="tipoEnd">Type of address:</label>
        <div class="input-box">
           <div class="styled-select">
           <select id="comments_2" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="onestep">
              <option value="">Selecione</option>
              <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
              <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
           </select>
           </div>
        </div>
```

**Code updated in Observer.php file:**

```
if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

    // Force array type
    if(!is_array($oscOrderData['comments']))
        $oscOrderData['comments'] = array($oscOrderData['comments']);

    foreach($oscOrderData['comments'] as $comment) {
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```